# Positional arg starts with hyphen in argparse

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, argparse

Using `argparse`, is there a way to pass an argument that starts with hyphen, like below?

```
./py_custom_script -d
```

I'm adding a change to old script that takes an argument, where with and without hyphen the logic is different. Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34356461/577001), I thought of only using `positional` arg and apply conditional logic internally, but looks like argparse already interprets the one starts with hyphen as an `optional` arg.

Note that maintaining backward compatibility is a must for this. Both Py 2.7 and 3.x.

Comment: The convention is indeed for arguments which start with dashes to be options. If you have a file name argument, pass it as `./-d`. If you just want to pass it through somehow, and you are really sure you know what you are doing, maybe don't use `argparse` at all; or, more realistically, implement the option `-d` so that it prepends the string `-d` to the argument array internally.

Comment: There has been active debate as to what do with arguments that look like option flags.  The default action for argparse is to treat them as flags, not a arguments.  https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing